# FB.init has already been called

Tags: facebook, facebook-opengraph

I am building facebook iframe app. My application is loaded once (I receive signed_request once) and then I navigate through the pages in the iframe using internal domain links. I noticed that I see these strange messages both in Chrome and Firefox

```
FB.init has already been called - this could indicate a problem
```

I am pretty sure that this method is called only once and it seems Facebook wants me to call it once per application load (not once per page).

```js
window.fbAsyncInit = function() {
  FB.init({
    appId: param('facebook_app_id'),
    frictionlessRequests: true,
    oauth: true,
    channelUrl: site_url('/channel.html')
  })
}
```

What error (if any) am I making here?

Comment: I'm receiving the same error.. I've submitted a bug to facebook:
https://developers.facebook.com/bugs/223004254480286

Comment: please consider marking Tinuo's answer (http://stackoverflow.com/a/10421328/910325) as accepted, the bug was fixed btw.

Comment: I ran the Facebook Oauth example at http://www.permadi.com/tutorial/facebook-js-oauth-popup-centered/index.html  Even that has this bug in firefox console. Don't know what this bug is upto, but the login and logout process works seamlessly.

Answer (score 157, accepted):

From the moment you pass parameters to the `js.src` like `#xfbml=1&appId=X`, FB SDK will auto init itself and thus `FB.init` will try to reinit..
So in your code, you don't have to remove the `FB.init` function, just make sure you don't pass parameters in the code that loads asynchronously the JS SDK.

Replace this:

```js
js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/sdk.js#xfbml=1&appId=X";
```

With :

```js
js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/sdk.js";
```

Comment: I *think* this is the correct answer, can someone else having this problem confirm?

Comment: Tinou, I think this is the case. Can I also pass frictionlessRequests?

Comment: Actually if I replace, comments are not rendered any more :-)

Comment: @potomok : Your `Fb.init` function can remain as it is. Therefore all arguments (such as _frictionlessRequests_) can stay. Again, providing `js.src` without parameters only "download" the js file but doesn't init the SDK. Hope this is more clear.

Comment: Yes, it sounds reasonable, but comments plugin and like buttons stop working if you don't use xfbml=1&appId=X

Comment: @potomok, if you want to render the `xfbml` tags right after the initialization of the SDK just add the parameter `xfbml : true` in your `FB.init` function.

Comment: +1 Solved the duplicated initialization for me, too. Thanks! (PS: Also i can confirm what @Tinou said about xfbml rendering. Since i had it in my init anyway, i had no downside with removing the params.)

Comment: This is the correct answer, could the OP mark it as such to help future users? This was exactly what I was looking for.

Comment: This is definitely the solution, working as of 9th May 2013. Facebook doesn't make it clear that loading with extra params will auto-init. Anyone who already has the facebook JS sdk loaded and then copies source from the facebook like button be aware of the extra params that the like button code says you should fill in... this is only for those who don't already have the SDK loaded.

Comment: **Update**: You should replace `all.js` with `sdk.js` as per the new documentation.

Comment: confirmed. this helps and the buttons still load and stuff just move those # parameters into FB.init(params)

Answer (score 10):

If you really need to call init more than once you can do this:

```js
FB._initialized = false;
FB.init();
```

but it makes no sense to me, I have a little bit different problem, but it is also related to `FB.init has already been called - this could indicate a problem` message.

I have AJAX-based website where after each page load I need to render XFBML from HTML that I get from AJAX request (comments, like button and other):

```js
 <div class="fb-comments" data-href="{REMOVED}" data-num-posts="5" data-width="760" colorscheme="dark"></div>
```

To do this, you can run this when you need to render XFBML:

```js
FB.XFBML.parse();
```

Comment: Dmitrij, I call init() only once per page, however it looks like facebook wants init() to be called only once per iframe load or it does it automatically as Pawel assumes. If the first case is valid it would be really intesesting to see the code

Answer (score 0):

I've also had this problem. I simply removed `FB.init({...})` part and it started to work with following code:

```js
window.fbAsyncInit = function () {
    FB.Event.subscribe('auth.logout', function () {
        // subscribe parts
    });

    // here is where fb.init() code was
};
(function(d, s, id) {
  var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
  if (d.getElementById(id)) return;
  js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
  js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js#xfbml=1&appId=X";
  fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
}(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));
```

I guess it now auto inits code, so there is no need to do it manually. Now my code works again. I hope this helps.

Comment: well, how do you pass channelUrl and frictionlessRequests = true ?

Comment: I don't and it is not an issue in my case, because I use this code on site. However it might be problematic with iframe app. Maybe try adding another parameters after "#" in js path? (just an idea, I haven't tested it).